# Existence of an application from $S ^ 2$ to $S ^ 1$ that sends the equator of $S ^ 2$ over $S ^ 1$

Tags: algebraic-topology

I'm trying to find an application from $S^2$ to $S^1$ that sends the equator of $S^2$ homeomorphically over $S^1$, but I doubt if it exists or not.

I think it doesn't exist. I'm looking for some algebraic topology result with which to test it, but I can't find out what it is, could someone help me?

Thank you so much.

Comment: If there were a continuous function $f\colon S^2 \to S^1$ which induces a homeomorphism on the equator, then in particular you could restrict this function to one of the hemispheres. This defines a continuous map $D^2 \to S^1$ which is the identity map on the boundary and this implies there is a null-homotopy of the identity map $S^1 \to S^1$, which means it is contractible.

Answer (score 4):

It is not possible suppose such $f:S^2\rightarrow S^1$ exists, let $e$ the equator, there exists $H(t,x):e\rightarrow S^2$ such that $H(0,x)=x, x\in e, H(1,x)=y_0$ where $y_0$ is fixed.

Consider $G(t,x)=f(H(t,f^{-1}(x)))$ it defines a retract of $S^1$ to a point contradiction

Comment: It is not clear to me what the guy asked for...

Comment: I got the point!

Comment: Why do you know that the application $H$ exists?

Comment: Because $S^2$ is simply connected.

Answer (score 1):

As asked, this is easy. The answer is "yes"

You can define

$$
f(x, y, z) = \begin{cases}
(x, y) & z = 0\\
(1, 0) & z \ne 0
\end{cases}
$$

This is clearly a homeomorphism on the equator (i.e., $z = 0$). Unfortunately, it's not at all continuous. Then again, you didn't *ask* for a continuous map, although you probably intended to.

If you want a *continuous* map, let's first look at the case where we seek a map $g$ with the property that 
$$
g \circ i = id_{S^1}
$$
where 
$$
i: S^1 \to \Bbb R^3 : (x, y) \mapsto (x, y, 0).
$$
In this case, we have
$$
S^1 \overset{i}{\to} S^2 \overset{g}{\to} S^1,
$$
where the composition is the identity on $S^1$. That means that the corresponding map on the fundamental group is also the identity:
$$
\pi_1 S^1 \overset{i_*}{\to} \pi_1 S^2 \overset{g_*}{\to} \pi_1 S^1,
$$
but replacing each by the known groups, this becomes
$$
\Bbb Z\overset{i_*}{\to}0 \overset{g_*}{\to} \Bbb Z,
$$
which is impossible.

What about the more general case, where the homeomorphism defined by $g$'s restriction to the equator isn't the identity, so that 
$$
h = g \circ i
$$
is *some* homeomorphism of $S^1$ rather than the identity? That just adds one more arrow:

$$
\Bbb Z \overset{i_*}{\to} 0 \overset{g_*}{\to} \Bbb Z  \overset{h_*^{-1}}{\to} \Bbb Z,
$$

...but the same algebraic argument still holds.